# Find the minimum and maximum of $f(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2 +\sin(z)$ (how should I procced from here?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Given the function $f(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2 +\sin(z)$, I am asking to prove that $f$ is getting its golbal minima and global maxima on $\partial \mathcal{U}$, where $$\mathcal{U}=\left\{(x, y, z) \mid \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}<1, \frac{x^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{a^{2}}<1\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$$ and $$0<a<b.$$

What I did is first argue that $\partial \mathcal{U}$ closed but I do not know how to show that it is bounded and hence use Weierstrass theorem.

After that I defined $$\partial\mathcal{U}=\left\{(x, y, z) \mid \frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1, \frac{x^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{a^{2}}=1\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$$
and by using Lagrange multipliers $$\phi \left(x,y,z,\lambda _1,\lambda _2\right)=x^2+y^2+\sin\left(z\right)+\lambda _1\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1\right)+\lambda _2\:_{ }\left(\frac{x^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}-1\right)$$
taking the $\nabla \phi=0$ and getting the folowing:
$$2x+\frac{2x\lambda _1}{a^2}+\frac{2x\lambda \:_2}{b^2}=0$$
$$2x+\frac{2x\lambda _1}{b^2}+\frac{2y\lambda \:_2}{a^2}=0$$
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}=1$$
$$\cos(z)=0$$

Is my method true? How should I procced from here?

Comment: min value of $\sin(z)$ is $-1$ and max is $1$. So it is easy to see based on constraints that the min value of the function is also $-1$.

Comment: but this point is not in $\partial \mathcal{U}$

Comment: Why do you say so? This occurs when $x$ = $y$ = $0$.

Comment: x,y equal to zero does not satisfy $\partial U$ conditions

Comment: But that is because you have defined it incorrectly.

Comment: would you like to help me define it correctly?

Comment: I would solve it differently. If you try to solve it through Lagrange method, note that one of the two constraints is stronger than the other for different values of $x$ and $y$. You have to first get one combined constraint. Both constraints lead to area within two intersecting ellipses with the same center, major axes and minor axes ($0 \lt a \lt b$) - in one case the major axis is along x-axis and in another it is along y-axis. It is easy to see that maxima of $x^2+y^2$ occurs at 4 intersections of the two ellipses and minima at their center $(0,0)$. That is easier way to solve.

Comment: You say the "global" extrema of $f$. Do you mean over $\Bbb R^3$, or just $\overline \cal U$? You cannot show that $\cal U$ is bounded, because it clearly is not. There is no constraint on the values of $z$. However $\partial\cal U$ is closed, as it is $\overline {\cal U} \setminus U$ and $\cal U$ is open. But note that since $f$ is periodic in $z$, you can convert this to a problem on a bounded domain.